# Select the third div from bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i select the third div from bottom (i.e in this case, the div with "4")

```
<div class='elem'>1</div>
<div class='elem'>2</div>
<div class='elem'>3</div>
<div class='elem'>4</div>
<div class='elem'>5</div>
<div class='elem'>6</div>
```

I tried this but it selected last three divs.

```
$('div:gt(-3)').css('background':'red');
```

Kindly know that, i may not know the total divs(it's dynamic), but i only need to select the third div from bottom.

Comment: You can easily select last three with `JS` with `querySelectorAll` and then using `splice`

Comment: Will there always be sufficient child elements that the third-last element will always exist?

Comment: @David ...Not really..If possible check if it exists

Comment: @Sam. I think that is it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `eq()` method by specifying a value of **-3**, which will hover over the *third* element from the bottom.

```js
$('div:eq(-3)').css('background', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='elem'>1</div>
<div class='elem'>2</div>
<div class='elem'>3</div>
<div class='elem'>4</div>
<div class='elem'>5</div>
<div class='elem'>6</div>
```

Comment: @Theconcise, glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

If all you're trying to do is apply styling to that element:

```css
/* a simple reset so all elements have similar
   and consistent defaults: */
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* purely for aesthetics in order to visually
   separate each of the 'demo' blocks; using
   CSS logical properties to define margins: */
.demo {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-block: 1em;
  margin-inline: 0.5em;
}

/* to visually distinguish the selected elements: */
.elem:nth-last-child(3) {
  background-color: #f00;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  <div class="elem">1</div>
  <div class="elem">2</div>
  <div class="elem">3</div>
  <div class="elem">4</div>
  <div class="elem">5</div>
  <div class="elem">6</div>
  <div class="elem">7</div>
  <div class="elem">8</div>
  <div class="elem">9</div>
  <div class="elem">10</div>
</div>

<div class="demo">
  <div class="elem">1</div>
  <div class="elem">2</div>
  <div class="elem">3</div>
</div>

<div class="demo">
  <div class="elem">1</div>
</div>
```

If you instead need to use JavaScript, then I'd suggest the following:

```js
// defining an Arrow function, passing two arguments:
// selector: a String, CSS selector with which to select the elements,
// index: a Number, the 1-based index of the element starting from
//                  the end. The last element would be index 1, the
//                  penultimate element index 2:
const nthLastChild = (selector, index) => {

  // here we return an Array literal, which takes the spread operator and
  // converts the iterable NodeList returned from document.querySelectorAll()
  // and converts it into an Array:
  return [...document.querySelectorAll(
    // the template-literal we use to construct the CSS selector, we use a
    // template-literal in order to interpolate the JavaScript variables
    // into the String:
    `${selector}:nth-last-child( ${Math.abs(index)} )`
  )];
}

// because we return an Array, we can here use Array.prototype.forEach()
// - along with other Array methods - to perform operations on the returned
// elements:
nthLastChild('.elem', '-3').forEach(
  (el) => {
    el.style.color = '#fff';
    el.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
    el.style.background = 'linear-gradient(90deg, #f90, #fff)';
  });
```

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.demo {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-block: 1em;
  margin-inline: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  <div class="elem">1</div>
  <div class="elem">2</div>
  <div class="elem">3</div>
  <div class="elem">4</div>
  <div class="elem">5</div>
  <div class="elem">6</div>
  <div class="elem">7</div>
  <div class="elem">8</div>
  <div class="elem">9</div>
  <div class="elem">10</div>
</div>

<div class="demo">
  <div class="elem">1</div>
  <div class="elem">2</div>
  <div class="elem">3</div>
  <div class="elem">4</div>
</div>

<div class="demo">
  <div class="elem">1</div>
  <div class="elem">2</div>
  <div class="elem">3</div>
</div>

<div class="demo">
  <div class="elem">1</div>
</div>
```

References:

- CSS:
- `:nth-last-child()`.
- JavaScript:
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=document.queryselectorAll).
- [Spread (`...`) syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).
- [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Answer (score 0):

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".elem");
const lastThird = elements[elements.length - 3];
```

Comment: OP wants all `divs` from particular position, In this case it is 3rd last

Comment: I thought he only wanted the 3rd from the end of the array. `How can i select the third div from bottom (i.e in this case, the div with "4")`

Comment: @SAM: “* How can i select the third div...I tried this but it selected last three divs.*” - the OP does not seem to want “all `<div>` elements from that position*”

Comment: Apologies @FireFighter. You're right. OP wants only select the last third.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const allElem = [...document.querySelectorAll(".elem")];
allElem[allElem.length - 3].style.background = "red";
```

```html
<div class="elem">1</div>
<div class="elem">2</div>
<div class="elem">3</div>
<div class="elem">4</div>
<div class="elem">5</div>
<div class="elem">6</div>
<div class="elem">7</div>
<div class="elem">8</div>
<div class="elem">9</div>
<div class="elem">10</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `$('body div')[$('body div').length-3];` as a selector. This selects all the `<div>`s and then selects the third from the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to your problem will be to use nth-last-child() CSS property. add the following code in your CSS file.

```
.elem:nth-last-child(3){
background: red;
}
```